# Prevent home screen icon from stretching using Cordova

Tags: cordova, appicon, cordova-android

I'm struggling finding a way to prevent Cordova from stretching my App Icon for Android.

From my research, I was told to add padding but can't figure it out.

I changed the size of the image and also added more space around the image but to no avail. I use an image generator to generate the customizable image. They look good after generating but when I build, the image stretches.

Any idea on adding padding to app icon? Please share.

If anyone has another approach other than using padding, please share as well